# Android ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am using action bar sherlock and have three tabs showing absolutely fine. The problem I am having is that I can't seem to get the title showing at all, it literally shows three tabs at the top. When using the native action bar on the same project, it showed the title on one line, then the tabs underneith (split action bar). This time, only tabs. I do have the required elements in the manifest such as:

```
uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

I am using the theme `@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light`

Comment: If you change theme to something like `Theme.Sherlock`, same issue?

Comment: No, literally changes the colour scheme, but the problem remains...